# Temporary ad serving limit placed on your AdMob account

Tags: android, ios, admob

I am using admob since 3 years for showing ads in my application. I had single admob account for showing ads in my mobile applications. In october 2021 I received mail that ad serving limit placed on my account. So I created new admob account & shifted apps. Now I use different admob accounts for showing admob ads in my application.

Again I received mail that ad serving limit placed for one of my accounts. Good thing about it now I know which app is creating the issue but not sure of exact reason of invalid traffic & what changes to make in order to fix it.

I also noticed last app update was 5 months ago. So there is no recent app update that may have violated the policy.

As limit is again placed on my account I though of using the test id's in following cases

1. If device is rooted
2. usb is connected
3. App not installed from play store
   4 App attestation test api result failed.

I released new apk & thought that the issue will be resolved but again after 2 days of releasing apk I got mail again that ad serving limit is imposed.

That's very unfortunate Admob don't tell us exactly which policy is violated & what we need to do in order to fix it.

Please suggest me how to resolve this issue. I am facing huge financial lose as ads are not being served in my application. Is there is any way to contact admob support?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Napster
have you solved this issue ? i am facing same issue from last 4 months please help if possible thanks